# How would I test to find out if a resistor is nonohmic if I knew that the internal resistance of the battery is nonohmic?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I need to construct a circuit with an unknown resistor and a battery with an internal resistor. I am trying to find out if the unknown resistor is ohmic or not but the internal resistor is nonohmic so I don't know how to modify the procedure or the data analysis.

Comment: You need to explain what tools you have available. Do you have an ohmmeter, ammeter, known ohmic calibration resistors, …?  What voltage and current ranges are you interested in?